# Select exact matching columns from table in Zend...?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select, model

I am facing a strange issue in my Zend Application:

My model is like this:

```
 public function checkEmailAndProfileName($emailId, $proName) {
    $select = $this->select()
                     ->where('email_address = ?', $emailId)
                     ->where('profile_name = ?', $proName);
    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
 }
```

### Explanation

Suppose I have a row in database with email address "test@test.com" and profile name as "profilename".

Now if I pass following parameters to the model:

```
$modelObj->checkEmailAndProfileName("test@test.com", "profilename");
```

It is working fine as I want.

### Problem

Now If I pass:

```
$modelObj->checkEmailAndProfileName("test@test.com", "ProfileNAME");
```

Then it should return false, but strangely it is returning the row of "test@test.com", "profilename". That I don't want...

can anyone help me by telling What I am doing wrong...?

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) of mysql

Using `BINARY` in the `WHERE` clause forces a match on the binary collation, which in English means that it matches actual characters by their character code, not by whether the characters are deemed equivalent.

```
public function checkEmailAndProfileName($emailId, $proName) {
    $select = $this->select()
                     ->where('email_address = ?', $emailId)
                     ->where('BINARY profile_name = ?', $proName);
    $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
 }
```